# array output not correct

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I am using 2 classes and a bunch of methods to store something in an array then writing it to a file. After I write something to a file, instead of being of the var double,
this is my code:

```
public void storeArray(Quest1 a, Quest2 b, String filename) throws   FileNotFoundException{

PrintWriter k = new PrintWriter(filename);
for(int i = 0; i < a.getDays(); i++)
{
    k.println(b.storeArr(a));
}

k.close();
System.out.println("Written.");
}
```

Quest 1 is a class, Quest 2 is a class and String filename is just getting passed through.
After doing all that and putting the Quest3 object in my main menu.
I run the program, input all my values etc which get put into an array in the class Quest 2 and then I write them to a file.

I open that file to check if it has worked and i get this:

```
     [D@264532ba
```

How do I fix that to get my double variables in the file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Print out `Arrays.toString` instead of just print out the array (which invokes its `toString` inherited from `Object`):

```
k.println(Arrays.toString(b.storeArr(a)));
```

Or if you want some custom format, you can use `StringUtils.join` from Apache Commons. Or, perhaps just write a loop if you cannot use any dependencies.

The thing you output is the `toString` of the array, which is its type (`[D`) + `@` + its hash code (`264532ba`).

Comment: i did that, not its printing in 2 dimensions, i dont have 2 dimensions

Comment: It returns the value of the array joined with `,` and enclosed in `[]`, but what do you mean by "2 dimensions"?

Comment: i thought that was 2 dimensions, sorry. but i understand now. why exactly does it print it enclosed [] with that?

Comment: That's how it works, I can't say why: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString(long[]) All the others are working in the same way.

Answer (score 1):

Arrays use the default implementation of `toString()` and that's why the output of the array is:

```
[D@264532ba
```

You have two options to print an array's content:

- Iterate over each element.
- Use `Arrays.toString(array)`.

---

## Explanation of the weird output

Let me explain the following code:

```
double[] array = new double[10];
System.out.println(array);
```

`array` is an object, hence you are calling [`println(Object)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println(java.lang.Object)) of [`PrintStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html) (`System.out`), which calls `toString()` on the passed object internally. The array's `toString()` is similar to [Object](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html)'s [`toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString()):

```
getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode());
```

So the output would be something like:

```
[D@756a7c99
```

where `[` represnts the depth of the array, and `D` refers to `double`. `756a7c99` is the value returned from [`hashCode()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode()) as a hex number.

Read also [`Class.getName()` JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getName()).

Answer (score 0):

if `storeArr` returns an Array, you could use `Arrays.toString(b.storeArr(a))`

Answer (score 0):

This here:

```
k.println(b.storeArr(a));
```

You are printing `b.storeArr(a)` which is an array object.

Just do this:

```
PrintWriter k = new PrintWriter(filename);
for(int i = 0; i < a.getDays(); i++)
{
    b.storeArr(a);
    k.println(Arrays.toString(b));
}
```